# Should I be concerned about my contractor not being lead certified

Tags: paint, renovation, demolition, contractors, lead

Wife and I live in a 1950s house. We’ve been planning a whole house renovation for months and finally found a GC we like.

We learned he isn’t qualified to work on lead-containing materials. He’s done work in loads of houses in the area, has great references, etc.

There’s a legal statute called RRP that contractors to be certified, but when I asked him he didn’t seem concerned that he wasn’t certified. I looked up the other contractors we interviewed and only one of the other 5 were certified.

Our first child is due right after the work is expected to finish and I’m worried about lead dust lingering after the work is done.

We already have subbed out to an asbestos remediation company for demoing the interior walls, but our GC would be demoing exterior walls, windows, and some of the roof for an addition. Also doing electrical and plumbing work.

My wife doesn’t seem too concerned and thinks I’m overreacting since we won’t be living in the house during the work.

Should I get a new contractor? Should I sub out the demo to someone else who is certified? Am I overreacting?

Comment: Have you tested the paints in the interior and exterior of the house for lead? What about pipes?  In other words, before you worry about lead contamination, it might be worthwhile to test the materials and find if there is any lead present at all.

Comment: @RibaldEddie A 1950s house is virtually guaranteed to have lead paint. But the people at risk are the people doing the work. As long as the job site is cleaned up reasonably well and all previously painted surfaces are either replaced or repainted before the family moves back in, this is pretty much a non-issue.

Comment: I wouldn't be concerned if he is doing outside work while you aren't living there.  Lead was commonly used in gasoline and pretty much all city soil is contaminated.  When other people are renovating their old houses on the exterior are you moving away while construction is occurring within a two block radius to avoid any dust in the wind?  Have you looked into the regs for outside work?  I think they are fairly loose and mostly about protecting the worker who is doing this day in / day out.

Comment: @FreshCodemonger The exterior regulations are pretty rigorous as well. If lead work is taking place (more than 20sqft). Barriers must be erected if within 10ft of a property line. You must also either capture or clean all visible paint chips. The regs aren't about necessarily protecting the workers, it is all protecting kids.

Comment: @matt. But as long as the place is cleaned up of any debris afterwards—as I'm assuming—what's the problem?  The family isn't living there during construction.

Comment: @Huesmann If a proper cleanup is done, no problem. But, it comes down to this, if your contractor isn't willing to spend the small amount of money and time to do it the right way, the *legal* way, why would you trust them to work on your project? I'm by no means a led expert, but, I am a lot more knowledgeable on the subject now after taking the class. Again, you are legally required to have the cert if working in pre 1978 buildings and can be fined up to $36 per violation.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I would be concerned.

I just finished my RRP certification. You are legally required to have an RRP cert if you're working on a pre 1978 house/building. If you're disturbing more than 6 sqft inside or 20 sqft exterior. Regardless of the presence of lead, records must be kept for 3 years with the potential for hefty fines.

Kids under 6 are prone to issues with lead contamination. These medical issues are well documented. There is also the issue of cross contamination if the work is not performed correctly and things are not cleaned correctly. Only certified renovators are able to sign off on the final clean and must train non-certified workers.

After taking my cert, I wouldn't allow someone to work in my house if they weren't certified OR could demonstrate that they have the ability to perform the work to those standards. While others may think this isn't a big deal, I wouldn't trust my kids health and well-being to someone who isn't certified. Simple as that.

Comment: helpful to hear from someone with the cert.  curious about the exterior barriers what do those look like?  I had a building torn down with lead painted asbestos siding - certified abatement people took it down but since it was exterior and non friable the precautions were minimal.  if you aren't sanding something then you just worry about chips or pieces that break off during removal.  inside is a different story.

Comment: Exterior barriers can be as complex as scaffolding and essentially tenting the building or as simple as hanging plastic from the fascia.  We were also told that the materials needed to be *secure* while transporting to a landfill, meaning, a cover if going in a trailer or a simple as lining a dumpster with plastic and making a giant burrito.  I'm not saying that the work *can't* be done by non certified persons (legally the cannot) but knowing how to do it correctly matters. Cleanup is equally important. No visible paint chips left behind. The fines are quite extensive, around $36k.

Comment: @matt. I was thinking my next steps would  be to test the paint at my windowsills and exterior. If it’s positive i’ll scope having a professional do the demolition. (Right now I’m assuming it is because of age). My wife thinks I’m overreacting and that the risk is negligible. It’s hard to make a judgement when everyone involved has a conflict of interest. Lead abatement pros obviously want the business, and so does my contractor.

Comment: @FauxBreakfast Lead enters the blood stream and moves to the brain, once there it coats the synapses which causes a variety of issues. My suggestion would be to do some research yourself and present her with your findings. Kids are worth the extra effort, they're a gift to be cherished.

Comment: Nothing incorrect here, but also as an RRP certified individual, I’ll say that I wouldn’t be as concerned as matt. That’s mainly because you aren’t living in the house during the reno. When the smashing is going on, it’ll be dusty and dangerous for the trades; however, when you move back in, there shouldn’t be a speck of dust anywhere. Any existing woodwork will hopefully be encapsulated with fresh paint. I would echo the suggestion to capture paint chips in plastic outside.

Comment: It’s probably worth mentioning that RRP certification isn’t hard to get. Its presence/absence might be an indication of how committed your GC is to excellent quality/ compliance/ competence.

Comment: Exactly the point. If your GC isn't willing to spend the small amount of money and have someone sit through an 8 hour class and take a test then how/why should you trust them with your families health. Especially when it is *LEGALLY* required? Do you hire unlicensed contractors with no bond? Seems pretty careless to me. @AloysiusDefenestrate